# Android Accelerometer Skipping Frames

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sensormanager

I have finally have figured out how to implement the accelerometer in Android, but it seems to be skipping frames. I suspect this because when I use the acceleration data like this :

```
velX += event.values[0]*(deltaTime/1000);
velY += event.values[1]*(deltaTime/1000);
velZ += event.values[2]*(deltaTime/1000);
```

to convert the acceleration in m/s to velocity in m/(time the frame took). This looks like it would behave fine, except for some unintended behavior. For example, with velY, if I move the phone upwards and stop, velY becomes a really large negative. It seems, that there is more deceleration than acceleration.

I then calculated the FPS to see if I was actually getting the least sensor delay possible like I specified with `sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);`

I also tested an app on the Google Play Store called `Accelerometer Analyzer` and found that it was getting 260 FPS, while my app was getting `onSensorChanged()` calls around 130 times per second. this even happened when I emptied the method and replaced it with just the FPS counter.

You can see this effect in this graph snippet of the velocity while moving the device upward quickly and then stopping.

[image: Graph of velocity while moving phone upwards]

Somehow the velocity becomes negative.

Hopefully someone knows the problem.

**EDIT:** I would like to confirm that I am using the `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` and not `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`